# How to properly append on change of a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple select input that allows multiple choice. What I'm trying to do is simply display in the PRE the selected choice(s) into spans. It seems to be working fine when it comes to single selections but not when selecting multiple choices.

For example if I select multiple choices, in my PRE it only displays 1 item instead of an array.

Script:
https://jsfiddle.net/

```
$('#selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var test = $('#selectpicker').val();
    $.each(test, function (value) {
    $('#pre_support').html("");
    $('#pre_support').append("<span class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>"+this+"</span>");
    });
});
```

Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: jsfiddle does not work!

Comment: Sorry forgot to hit save, here is the working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1buuq3dd/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are clearing the innerHtml of `pre_support` it in every iteration of the `$.each` loop. So it is going to overwrite the content you set to `""`.

Move it outside of the loop.

```
$('#pre_support').html(""); 
$.each(test, function (value) {       
    $('#pre_support').append("<span class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>"+this+"</span>");
});
```

Comment: That makes more sense thanks here is the working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1buuq3dd/.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your correction please check it once.

```
$('#selectpicker').on('change', function(){

    var test = $('#selectpicker').val();

    $('#pre_support').html("");

    $.each(test, function (value) {
        $('#pre_support').append("<span class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>"+this+"</span>");
    });
});
```

Here is [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bgd177L8/1/) you can check it.

Your mistake is you cleared html in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you and believe that you are looking for this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectpicker').on('change', function() {
    $('#pre_support').html("");
    var test = $('#selectpicker').val();
    $.each(test, function(value) {
      $('#pre_support').append("<span class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>" + this + "</span>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectpicker">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test 5</option>
  <option value="6">Test 6</option>
</select>
<span id="pre_support"></span>
```